Pre-bound JDBC Connection found!JpaTransactionManager doesnot supportrunning withinDataSourceTransactionManager if toldto manage theDataSource itself
In my application I am using single data source and single jpa transaction manager. I am using Java version of 11 and spring version of 2.5.2.  Here is my config
@Bean
@Primary
@DependsOn({
    "env"
})
@Profile("!local")
@Qualifier("pg_RPRDB_DataSource")
public HikariDataSource pg_RPRDB_DataSource() {
    AwsSecrets awsSecrets = secretsConfig == null ? null : secretsConfig.awsSecrets();
    logger.info("Secrets :" + awsSecrets.toString());
    String url = "";
    if (awsSecrets != null) {
        String host = awsSecrets.getRPR_DB_WRITE_HOST() == null ? awsSecrets.getRPR_DB_HOST() : awsSecrets.getRPR_DB_WRITE_HOST();
        logger.info("Filling secrets from AWS secrets RPR DB " + host);
        url = "jdbc:" + awsSecrets.getRPR_DB_ENGINE() + "://" + host + "/" + awsSecrets.getRPR_DB_NAME()\ + "?jaasApplicationName=pgjdbc"\ + "&user=" + awsSecrets.getDB_USERNAME();
    }
    logger.info("URL for RPR database" + url);
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
    dataSource.setMinimumIdle(10);
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(60000);
    dataSource.setPoolName("RPRDB");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("options", "-c search_path=test,public,pg_catalog -c statement_timeout=5000");
    dataSource.setDataSourceProperties(properties);
    logger.info("Number of max connections : " + dataSource.getMaximumPoolSize());
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "pg_RPRDB_EntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("pg_RPRDB_DataSource") HikariDataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("com.icwgroup.ratingsengine.db.entity")
        .persistenceUnit("RPRDB")
        .build();
}

@Bean(name = "pg_RPRDB_TransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("pg_RPRDB_EntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(pg_RPRDB_DataSource());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}

I even set the property spring.autoconfigure.exclude : org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
This didn't work. Please let me know where I am going wrong.
My application is in production from past 8 months .. now I am seeing this error .. I did not change any config related to data source.
This application hosted on AWS ECS and I am using postgresql db.
Error Trace:
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:400)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at com.icwgroup.ratingsengine.db.repository.RatingDAORepository.saveResponseData(RatingDAORepository.java:118)
at com.icwgroup.ratingsengine.db.repository.RatingDAORepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a8f05036.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209)
at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
at com.icwgroup.ratingsengine.db.repository.RatingDAORepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14188789.saveResponseData(<generated>)
at com.icwgroup.ratingsengine.businesslogic.xldp.XldpProcessor.saveData(XldpProcessor.java:123)
at com.icwgroup.ratingsengine.businesslogic.xldp.XldpProcessor.processXldpRequest(XldpProcessor.java:87)
at com.icwgroup.ratingsengine.api.xldp.XldpApiController.processXldpRequest(XldpApiController.java:31)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


Remove the setDataSource call from the JpaTransactionManager.

Sorry Deinum .. this didn't work
